# nsstring and nsinteger conversion

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have two arrays, the first one contents numbers and the second one use this numbers as indexes.

```
NSArray *dayOfWeek = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"D",@"L",@"M", @"X",@"J",@"V",@"S", nil];

NSArray *arrayDays = [days componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];     

 //arrayDays  2 3 4 5 6 

     NSString *daysPrint;

     for (NSString *theDay in arrayDays) {
         NSLog(@"string %@",theDay);
         NSInteger dayIndex = (NSInteger)theDay;
         NSLog(@"integer %d", dayIndex);
         daysPrint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", daysPrint, [dayOfWeek objectAtIndex:dayIndex]];

     }
```

in the log:

```
2012-07-02 12:49:27.322 usualBike[1698:f803] string 2
2012-07-02 12:49:27.323 usualBike[1698:f803] integer 109471840
```

And obviously when I try to get dayOfWeek[109461840] it crashes.

How can I solve this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: NSArray *arrayDays = [days componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] in this "days" is a string?use NSLog to print "days".to get "dayIndex",use [theDay intValue].

Comment: The string daysPrint is coming out to be null and also dayOfWeek has no element for index dayIndex.

Comment: How you getting the "days" string.Please add some code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this

```
 for (NSString *theDay in arrayDays) {
    NSLog(@"string %@",theDay);
    NSInteger dayIndex = [theDay intValue];     // change this code
    NSLog(@"integer %d", dayIndex);
    daysPrint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", daysPrint, [dayOfWeek objectAtIndex:dayIndex]];

}
```

Answer (score 10):

daysPrint is comming null. u need to assing it blank value, this is the cause of crash

```
NSArray *dayOfWeek = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"D",@"L",@"M", @"X",@"J",@"V",@"S", nil];

NSArray *arrayDays = [days componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];     

//arrayDays  2 3 4 5 6 

NSString *daysPrint=@"";

for (NSString *theDay in arrayDays) {
    NSLog(@"string %@",theDay);
    NSInteger dayIndex = [theDay intValue];
    NSLog(@"integer %d", dayIndex);
    daysPrint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", daysPrint, [dayOfWeek objectAtIndex:dayIndex]];

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for (NSString *theDay in arrayDays) {
     NSLog(@"string %@",theDay);
     int dayIndex = [theDay intValue];
     NSLog(@"integer %d", dayIndex);
     daysPrint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", daysPrint, [dayOfWeek objectAtIndex:dayIndex]];

 }
```

may this will help you...

Answer (score 3):

You can use NSString instance method like [theDay intValue] for integer conversion. No need to cast yourself.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

USE

```
NSInteger dayIndex = [theDay intValue];
```

instead